# How to center H1 and nav

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my H1 and nav by using `text-align: center;` although when I do this my nav is not reaching the center and is not under my h1 as I want it to be. Currently my nav does not reach under my H1 and is too far to the left, what do I need to add to my nav to be able to center it correctly under my H1.

[image: What my website currently looks like.]

[image: What I want to achieve]

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #ededed;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main-h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.mobile-nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.mobile-nav>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.mobile-nav>ul>li>a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main-h1">Main</h1>
<nav class="mobile-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: it's perfectly centred, but you what you want is not center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that your h1 and nav are correctly centred in the page.

Your design are not, so if you want the same result as your design, you gonna need to add a margin, for example :

```
.mobile-nav>ul>li:first-child {
    margin-left: 22px;
 }
```

but i don't really recommend it

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to set width for the li elements

```
.mobile-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 20px;
  **width: 100px;**
}
```

so text-align: center is inherited from ul

here is the code

http://plnkr.co/edit/88Dy8v9AzB5uMSpiiVfR?p=preview